# select2 in the table is changed by other select2 cilcked

Tags: jquery, html, select, jquery-select2

here is code

```js
//multi_select
$(".multi-select").select2({
  allowClear: true,
  width: "100%"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td class="bold">ordering</td>
  <td colspan="2">
    <select class="multi-select" multiple="multiple">
         <option>test:test1</option>
         <option>test:test1</option>
         <option>test:test1</option>
         <option>test:test1</option>
         <option>test:test1</option>
         <option>test:test1</option>
   </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="bold">manufacturing</td>
  <td colspan="2">
    <select class="multi-select" multiple="multiple">
       <option>test:test1</option>
       <option>test:test1</option>
       <option>test:test1</option>
       <option>test:test1</option>
       <option>test:test1</option>
       <option>test:test1</option>
     </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="bold">tech-group</td>
  <td colspan="2">
    <select class="multi-select" multiple="multiple">
      <option>test:test1</option>
      <option>test:test1</option>
      <option>test:test1</option>
      <option>test:test1</option>
      <option>test:test1</option>
      <option>test:test1</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="bold">field-verification</td>
  <td colspan="2">
    <select class="multi-select" multiple="multiple">
       <option>test:test1</option>
       <option>test:test1</option>
       <option>test:test1</option>
       <option>test:test1</option>
       <option>test:test1</option>
       <option>test:test1</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I using same class at the select-options.
and if I changed "manufacturing" value, the bottoms select2(tech-group and field-verification)'s width is
changed by calculated its outside.

I really want know why and how can i fix it.
thank you.

Comment: That is Happening because you are using a table here. So, Whenever you try to insert something in first or any other select input, the whole column width get increased. So If you want to do it separately write them out of table.

Comment: As you say, Does select2 can't using table?